# Disable autocorrect in the Tags input field

Tags: feature-request

Please explicitly disable `autocorrect` on the Tags `input` field. On Stack Overflow when I type in "uibutton" OS X wants very much so to replace it with "unbutton" because you haven't told it autocorrect is inappropriate for this field, and indeed it is not appropriate there. There are many tags that aren't words you'd find in the dictionary.

For those unfamiliar with the autocorrect behavior, after you type a word then hit space, it will replace the incorrect word with a word it believes you meant to type. Therefore typing "uibutton" and hitting space replaces it with "unbutton". "unbutton" ins't a tag on SO, so when I went to post it thankfully prompted me to confirm I wanted to create a new tag, which is how I noticed the issue. There could be cases where the user doesn't notice the replacement occurred and it replaced it with a different word that is an existing tag. So questions could pretty easily be tagged with tags the OP didn't intend to add.

A temporary workaround is to type in "UIButton" for example which avoids the problem because OS X is smart enough to know the difference, but because tags are lowercase I don't think to do that.

Note that this is also a problem in Safari and Chrome on iOS (I believe all browsers on iOS as all must use Safari's Webkit engine). It may also be encountered by other platforms/browsers that offer autocorrect functionality, or will in the future.

[image]

Comment: `autocorrect` is a non-standard attribute only supported by Safari.

Comment: That's really not something for SE to "fix". It's up to the browser, and user. Here is the first Google result for "OS X disable auto correct": https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/turn-autocorrect-osx-mac-mail-skype-10-9-mavericks/

Comment: No no, I certainly want autocorrect enabled for example in the Title input and main content textview, SE should disable it only in the Tags input field. @ShadowWizard.

Comment: Still, as @Nathan mentions, this isn't a standard HTML attribute, but rather something specific only to Apple. For other OS, it's just noise. So, I'm not sure SE should add noise to their code just to fix something for very specific set of users. They still might, I am not downvoting or voting to close this, just sharing my opinion, and possibly a reason why this will be eventually declined.

Comment: Thanks for noting that @ShadowWizard, but I believe it should be fixed, even if it's not an official standard and it's only (currently) affecting all browsers on iOS (all must use Webkit) and at least Safari on OS X, as it can result in unintended consequences - incorrect tags being applied to questions. I just updated the post to explain that.